# Combine two rows together

Tags: php

Maybe someone can help me out. Any help is appreciated! I'm trying to Combine the "???" row with "unknown files" row. So the total would be 4245. Just one row.

I'm using a while loop. Here is my code

[image]

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to Database";

$query = "SELECT company, username, COUNT(company), username FROM AdTracking WHERE DATE(dmy) = CURRENT_DATE GROUP BY company ORDER BY company ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<div style='margin-top:100px;'><center><h2>";
echo date(' \ F jS Y  - l');
echo "<br />";
echo "</h2><center></div>";


echo '
<center> <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Users</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
';


// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><strong>" .($row['company'] == NULL ? "???" : $row['company']). "</strong></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(company)'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> ... </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}


echo '
    </tbody>
</table> </center>
';

?>
```

Comment: What will be used for the company name? `???` or `unknown file`?

Comment: This could also be solved with a sql query and become a permanent solution. Or do you just need to alter the data in this specific view

Comment: means do you want to add **Total** of first and last rows? OR they are the specific entries with data `???` and `unknown file`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. My output needs to have ??? and unknown file combined together.  So my html table should only show "unknown file" but have the total of ??? as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to calculate total of `???` and `unknown file` outside the `while loop`

```
$total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['company'] == NULL || $row['company'] == "unknown file")
        $total += $row['COUNT(company)'];
}
```

Then you can use that total in the main output loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><strong>" .($row['company'] == NULL ? "???" : $row['company']). "</strong></td>";
    if($row['company'] == "unknown file")
        echo "<td>" . $total . "</td>";
    else
        echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(company)'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> ... </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```